# I want to call a Java method using a 2D array of values. How do I set up my for loop to call the method correctly?

Tags: java, arrays

In my main class I have:

```
String[][] ships = {{"Bismarck.png","Rodney.png"},{"170", "50"},{"20", "220"}};

BattleScene scene = new BattleScene(ships);
```

I am trying to call this method:

```
  public void createScene() {
   for(int i = 0; i < ships[0].length; i++ ){
      for(int j = 0; j < ships.length; j++){
        drawImage(ships[i][0], ships[i][1], ships[i][2], 250, 7);
      }
     }
```

How do I set up my nested for loop to grab my values without me putting in the second array index by hand?

I haven't got a clue what to try. But I know I want it to call the method using a 2D array nested for loop.

Comment: Don't you mean `ships[0][i]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need two loops.

Since the first dimension of the array is going to always be `3` you simply need to create an iteration for whatever the length of at least one indice is.

Then, for clarity, just create some variables to store your values in, before passing them to `drawImage`.

```java
public void createScene() {
    String[][] ships = {{"Bismarck.png","Rodney.png"},{"170", "50"},{"20", "220"}};
    String filename;
    String x, y;
    for (int index = 0; index < ships[0].length; index++) {
        filename = ships[0][index];
        x = ships[1][index];
        y = ships[2][index];
        drawImage(filename, x, y, 250, 7);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to recommend a re-factor. It looks like you're trying to display image files using their filenames and dimensions. Rather than using a 2d array, I recommend creating a `ShipImage` class:

```
public class ShipImage {
    private String fileName;
    private String width;
    private String height;

    // appropriate constructors and mutators
}
```

And storing that in one of Java's `Collection` types. If order matters, you could use a LinkedHashSet:

```
    // other code
    Set shipImages = new LinkedHashSet<ShipImage>();
    //I'm guessing what values accompany which ship
    shipImages.add(new ShipImage("Bismarck.png", "170","20"));
    shipImages.add(new ShipImage("Rodney.png","50","220"));
```

Assuming `createScene` is a method of class `BattleScene`, that class might look something like this:

```
public class BattleScene {
    private Set<ShipImage> shipImages;

    public BattleScene(Set<ShipImage> shipImages) {
        this.shipImages = shipImages;
    }

    public void drawScene() {
        //since the shipImages are stored in a class derived from Collection, we can trivially iterate over them
        for(ShipImage image : shipImages) {
            drawImage(image);
        }
    }

    private void drawImage(ShipImage shipImage) {
        // logic for drawing the image
    }
}
```

Note: edited based on Reilas's comment to note that LinkedHashSet preserves order

Comment: Use a `LinkedHashSet` to preserve the order, use a `HashSet` to order by ascending values.